# need to replace 2 things from a csv file; one is Y with 'Y and the the newline charater by ',' value

Tags: shell, unix, csv

I need to replace 2 things from a csv file using Unix shell scripting ; one is Y with 'Y and the newline character by ',' value..

my csv:(values will be one below another vertically and all values start with Y)

```
YC1234
YC5678
```

expected output is NEEDED IN A LINE horizontally like :

```
'YC1234','YC5678'
```

kindly help as i am new to shell scripting...

i tried sed by its difficult in removing newline

```
cat master_upd.csv | sed -e 's//'\'','\''/g' | sed 's/\n/ /'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tr '\n' ',' < master.csv
```

The first command 'cat' is probably unnecessary.

Comment: but how to ' at the end of the value

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread on replacing newlines with something else using `sed`: [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)

```
sed -e 's/^.*$/'\''&'\''/' master_upd.csv | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'
```

The first `sed` puts in the single quotes, the second one replaces newlines with commas. Notice that I removed the cat and just told sed to open your file directly.

Comment: i receive the below error:

Label too long: :a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g

Comment: Worked for me. What version of `bash` do you have?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v q="'" 'NR>1{printf ","}{printf "%s",q$0q}END{print ""}' file
```